# Не отрабатывается исключение по ветке else

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Требуется если обнаружено исключение и прошло менее 10 минут с отправки сообщения, то выдавать сообщение «Ваше обращение было отправлено ранее»

````
import re
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from fastapi import HTTPException
from config import EMAIL_ADRESS_FROM, EMAIL_ADRESS_TO, PASSWORD
LAST_MSG_TIME = {}
APPEAL_FLAG = {}
TIME_THRESHOLD_SECONDS = 600
def send_to_email(subject, text):
   msg = MIMEMultipart()
   msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADRESS_FROM
   msg['To'] = EMAIL_ADRESS_TO
   msg['Subject'] = subject
   msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain'))
   try:
       with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.ru', 587) as server:
           server.starttls()
           server.login(EMAIL_ADRESS_FROM, PASSWORD)
           server.send_message(msg)
       print('Email sent')
   except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
       print(f'Sending email failed. Error: {str(e)}')
def union_exclusion(text):
   warnings = check_warnings(text)
   return '; '.join(warnings)
def check_warnings(text):
   warnings = []
   if re.search(r'[A-ZА-Я]{3,}', text):
       warnings.append('Повышенный тон')
   if re.search(r'\?{2,}', text):
       warnings.append('Повышенная эмоциональная нагрузка(?)')
   if re.search(r'!!{2,}', text):
       warnings.append('Повышенная эмоциональная нагрузка(!)')
   return warnings
def process_message(message):
   user_id = message.from_user_id
   current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
   if user_id not in LAST_MSG_TIME:
       LAST_MSG_TIME[user_id] = current_time
       APPEAL_FLAG[user_id] = False
   new_text = message.text
   violation_check = union_exclusion(new_text)
   if violation_check:
       if APPEAL_FLAG[user_id]:
           time_difference = current_time - LAST_MSG_TIME[user_id]
           if time_difference.total_seconds() <= TIME_THRESHOLD_SECONDS:
               subject_primary = f'Обращение от пользователя {message.first_name}({message.from_user_id})'
               text_primary = f'Пользователь {message.first_name}({message.from_user_id}) отправил обращение: \n{new_text}'
               send_to_email(subject_primary, text_primary)
               return f'{message.first_name}: вы совершили нарушения: {violation_check}\n\nОбращение зафиксировано'
           else:
               return f'{message.first_name}: Ваше обращение было отправлено в службу сопровождения ранее.'
       LAST_MSG_TIME[user_id] = current_time
       APPEAL_FLAG[user_id] = True
   else:
       if APPEAL_FLAG[user_id]:
           time_difference = current_time - LAST_MSG_TIME[user_id]
           if time_difference.total_seconds() <= TIME_THRESHOLD_SECONDS:
               if re.search(r'\bбот\b', new_text, re.IGNORECASE):
                   msg = re.sub(r'\bбот\b', '', new_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip()
                   errs = union_exclusion(msg)
                   if errs:
                       subject_primary = f'Обращение от пользователя {message.first_name}({message.from_user_id})'
                       text_primary = f'Пользователь {message.first_name}({message.from_user_id}) отправил обращение: \n{msg}'
                       send_to_email(subject_primary, text_primary)
                       return f'{message.first_name}: вы совершили нарушения: {errs}\n\nОбращение зафиксировано'
                   else:
                       subject_primary = f'Обращение от пользователя {message.first_name}({message.from_user_id})'
                       text_primary = f'Пользователь {message.first_name}({message.from_user_id}) отправил обращение: \n{msg}'
                       send_to_email(subject_primary, text_primary)
                       return f'{message.first_name}: Обращение зафиксировано'
               else:
                   return f'{message.first_name}: Ваше обращение было отправлено в службу сопровождения ранее.'
       subject_primary = f'Обращение от пользователя {message.first_name}({message.from_user_id})'
       text_primary = f'Пользователь {message.first_name}({message.from_user_id}) отправил обращение: \n{new_text}'
       send_to_email(subject_primary, text_primary)
       LAST_MSG_TIME[user_id] = current_time
       APPEAL_FLAG[user_id] = True
       return f'{message.first_name}: Обращение зафиксировано' ```
````

Comment: Тяжело такой "сплошной" код читать, да и отлаживать. Вы бы его порефакторили на небольшие функции для начала. У вас тут явно однотипные же куски кода повторяются. Читать и понимать код это сильно мешает.